# Connecting line segments to create closed regions

Tags: computer-vision, graph-theory, image-segmentation, undirected-graph

I am working on the problem of trying to segment an image based on straight edges to try to get closed quadrilaterals. I have been able to extract line segments using an edge detector. 
[image: Line Segments]

Is there a good way to connect edges that would be "nearly coincident" if extended so as to eventually create closed regions that can segment the image.